# matrix based on vector and diagonal elements=1 using matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I create the following matrix

```
1  0  0  0  0 
k1 1  0  0  0 
k2 k1 1  0  0
k3 k2 k1 1  0
k4 k3 k2 k1 1
```

Comment: where is your vector? [k1,...kn]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [TOEPLITZ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/toeplitz.html).

E.g.

```
vector = [1 2 3 4 5]; %# replace this with values for [1 k1 k2 k3 k4]
out = toeplitz(vector,[1 0 0 0 0])
out =
     1     0     0     0     0
     2     1     0     0     0
     3     2     1     0     0
     4     3     2     1     0
     5     4     3     2     1
```

---

**EDIT**

> my vector is [k1 k2 k3 k4 k5], how can
>   i apply tril or toeplitz?

Using @gnovice's more convenient formulation, you use

```
yourVector = [k1 k2 k3 k4 k5];
tril(toeplitz([1 yourVector(1:4)]))
```

Comment: The function [TRIL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/tril.html) could also be used to create a slightly different form of the above solution: `out = tril(toeplitz([1 k1 k2 k3 k4]));`

Comment: my vector is [k1 k2 k3 k4 k5], how can i apply tril or toeplitz?

Comment: the function tril(toeplitz([k1 k2 k3 k4 k5])) gives
k1 0  0  0  0
k2 k1 0  0  0
k3 k2 k1 0  0
k4 k3 k2 k1 0
k5 k4 k3 k2 k1

BUT the matrix i want is
1  0  0  0  0
k1 1  0  0  0 
k2 k1 1  0  0
k3 k2 k1 1  0 
k4 k3 k2 k1 1