# how can i create a matrix using vector with lag using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

```
vector=
3
4
8
5
2
1
6

the matrix i want to create is
3 0 0
4 3 0
8 4 3
5 8 4
2 5 8
1 2 5
6 1 2
```

Comment: please use some semblance of formatting so people can understand what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already covered in [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345236/matrix-based-on-vector-and-diagonal-elements1-using-matlab). Although you aren't trying to create a square matrix in *this* example, you can still use the [TOEPLITZ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/toeplitz.html) function like in [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345236/matrix-based-on-vector-and-diagonal-elements1-using-matlab/3345287#3345287):

```
M = toeplitz(vector,[vector(1) 0 0]);
```