# How can I create a matrix using vector k=[8 9 6 5 4 3]

Tags: matlab

How can I create the following  matrix?

```
[0 0 0 
8  0 0 
9  8 0 
6  9 8
5  6 9
4  5 6]
```

Comment: You keep asking variations of this [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345236/matrix-based-on-vector-and-diagonal-elements1-using-matlab) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357075/how-can-i-create-a-matrix-using-vector-with-lag-using-matlab). If you have read the documentation for [TOEPLITZ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/toeplitz.html) and [using matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-84787.html), you should be able to figure this out now. By the way, the answer is: `M = toeplitz([0 k(1:5)],[0 0 0]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [toeplitz](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/toeplitz.html) function?

```
c=[0 8 9 6 5 4 3]
r=[0 0 0]
t=toeplitz(c,r)
```

(Disclaimer: untested!)

T should be:

```
0 0 0
8 0 0 
9 8 0 
6 9 8 
5 6 9 
4 5 6 
3 4 5
```

Comment: the last element of the vector is 3 : in the matrix i want to creat  the last element in colomn1 is 4,  the matrix order is 6×3 When using the toeplitz(c,r) the last element in clo.1 =3 and the matrix order is 7×3 i want general rule to use in simulation

Comment: @blue: Sorry, I thought maybe it was just a typo that the "3" was missing.  Anyway, toeplitz sounds like exactly what you need; you just need to adjust the "c" ("column") argument to generate the output matrix you're looking for.